# Can we able to access tables from two different hive2 servers using multiple sparksessions

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Can we able to access tables from two different hive2 servers using two SparkSessions like below:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
  .appName("spark remote")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.160:3306/metastore?useSSL=false")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.175.160:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

val sparkdestination = SparkSession.builder().master("local") .appName("spark remote2")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.42:3306/metastore?useSSL=false")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", "hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", "hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.175.42:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql
val source = spark.sql("SELECT * from sample.source limit 20")

import sparkdestination.implicits._
import sparkdestination.sql
val destination = sparkdestination.sql("select * from sample.destination  limit 20")
```

Or is there is any possible way we can able to access two different database tables like `mysql-hive` for comaparison using multiple sparksessions.

Thank you

Comment: I dont think the connection is closed in the middle. Have you tried to pull a small data?

Comment: its working fine for small amount of data but in case of huge the connection is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my concern of how to use multiple SparkSession, its achieved by:

```
SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()
```

After clearing the sessions we can reassign it with different values.